# See who called make target

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

Is there a way you can tell who called a target in a make file. For example if in a make file I have the following

```
foo: bar

bar:
    gcc bar.c
    gcc foo.c
```

Is there any variable or another way in make to determine that foo called bar?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal here?

Comment: It was to see where the target was called from. Like to see that foo called bar since foo depends on bar.

Comment: Yes, but for what purpose? You can likely get similar information in a non-`-j` make with other changes as well as using `$?` in a target to find out which prerequisites are triggering it (which is the opposite of what you want but will tell you some of the same information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fundamentally two ways to solve this:

1. Dynamically: instrument your run of make so you will be able to see afterwards who called who. [MAKAO](http://mcis.polymtl.ca/makao.html) is a nice tool for this.
2. Statically: parse a Makefile to determine which dependencies *may be* called from which targets.

See also [an explanation I wrote some time ago](http://osdir.com/ml/help-make-gnu/2014-04/msg00011.html).

Answer (score 3):

Call `make -d` or `make -d 2>&1 | tee make.log`.  This tells you everything make is doing.  It's rather verbose, which is why you want to pipe it into a log file, which you can analyze better afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To do that I made the make file look like the following

```
foo: TARGET=foo

foo: bar

bar:
    @echo ${TARGET}
```

and got foo as the output

Comment: ... which is not really helpful I expect. If you have multiple targets which depends of a target which sets the variable, you got always the deepest one which is not what OP means I believe

Comment: It'll get you the most recent target that depended on the current target that set that variable. Whether that's useful or not depends on the goal here I think.

Comment: It was useful for what I wanted to do. But now I switched to a different way of the makefile setup to get to my goal.